# Vector reflect problem

Tags: xna, c#, vector

I'm testing some vector reflection and I want to check what happens when
a ball collides with a paddle.

So if I have:

```
Vector2 velocity = new Vector2(-5, 2); 
position_ball += velocity;

if (position_ball.X < 10) 
{
    Vector2 v = new Vector2(1,0); // or Vector2.UnitX   
    velocity = Vector2.Reflect(velocity, v); 
}
```

then, correctly, velocity is (5,2) after `Reflect`,
but if I do:

```
if (position_ball.X < 10)
{
  Vector2 v = new Vector2(1,1); 
  velocity = Vector2.Reflect(velocity, v);
}
```

then velocity is (1,8) and not (5, -2) that is 
the solution of reflection equation R = V - 2 * (V . N)

Why is that?

Comment: You've stepped through this with the debugger? I imagine your input values are not what you think they are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reflection equation is `R = V - 2 * (V . N) * N`
This formula also assumes that N is a normal vector, which it isn't in your case `new Vector2(1,1).Length() == 1.414...`

Try this instead:

```
if (position_ball.X < 10)
{
  Vector2 v = new Vector2(1,1); 
  v.Normalize();
  velocity = Vector2.Reflect(velocity, v);
}
```

The reflection of [-5,2] will actually be [-2,5] (or [1,8] if not normalized) and not [5,-2] as you assumed:

```
R = V - 2 * (V.N) * N
N = [1,1] * 2^-0.5
V = [-5,2]
```

Since Nx = Ny in this particular case we can refer to either of them as Nc

```
R = V - 2 * (v.N) * N
  = V - 2 * (Vx*Nc + Vy*Nc) * N
  = V - 2*Nc(Vx+Vy) * N
  = V - 2*Nc(-5+2) * N
  = V - 2*Nc(-3) * N
  = V + 6*Nc * N
  = V + [6*Nx*Nx, 6*Ny*Ny]
  = V + [6*Nx^2, 6*Ny^2]
  = [6*Nx^2-5, 6*Ny^2+2]
  = [6*(2^-1)-5, 6*(2^-1)+2]
  = [-2, 5]
```

`(N^a)^b = N^(a*b)` which is used in the above proof `(2^-0.5)^2 = 2^-1`

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the answer. If you have some time for me :) I still have a big doubt: if I normalize velocity Vector2.Reflect = (velocity, v) v is equal to 0.71 o.71 1.1 or always 1,1? and then if I want to reflect (-5, +2) into (5, -2) which equation should I use?

Comment: Normalize divides the vector with the length of the vector: `[1,1] / Sqrt(1^2 + 1^2) = [0.707..., 0.707...]` The formula is as I mentioned in the answer, but you can simply use `Vector2.Reflect` instead which uses that exact formula